Many errors in the colsole /browser/ after using lit-html cdns
I hosted my web site in Github Pages using lit-html (no lit element) from its cdns.
import { html, render } from '//unpkg.com/lit-html?module';
import { until } from '//unpkg.com/lit-html/directives/until?module';

But the browser's console fills up with lots of errors like:
"Loading module from “https://unpkg.com/lit-html@3.1.3/directives/private-async-helpers.js?module” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).",
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://unpkg.com/lit-html@3.1.3/directives/private-async-helpers.js?module. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)." and etc.
enter image description here
Does anyone have any idea why these errors occur and how could I solve them?
Thanks in advances for given time!
Greetings, Johanna Konova.
